# override database name for database class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I need to read database name from session (browser) and use this name for global db connection  (all db functions) instead of name stored in database.php. How should I override/extend MY_Loader.php to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...why do you want to do this? I have never known this to be done. You could extend the database class, to check the session for the database name, or I would maybe give this a try;

Before you load your database, you could load your session, and use that to define the database config;

```
$config['hostname'] = $this->session->userdata('db_hostname');
$config['username'] = $this->session->userdata('db_username');
$config['password'] = $this->session->userdata('db_password');
$config['database'] = $this->session->userdata('db_database');
// Now, load the database
$this->load->database($config);
```

Comment: this will work when you use it for a few functions in controller in small app. But for huge system it is not the best solution (code repetition again and again so it will be messy)

Comment: Or, add this to a library constructor, and autoload it?

Comment: maybe it should work (I tried various ways but I did something wrong). Finally I put retrieving from session directly in config/database.php